# Bash Script to Transfer File across Two Servers

Tags: bash, file, ssh, remote-access

I am writing a bash script to do the following: transfer a specific file to a jump server and then transfer the same file from the jump server to the final server. My original idea was to SCP the file and then SSH into the jump server and then SCP the file one more time, but the bash script terminates when I SSH into the jump server. I am relatively inexperienced with bash and was wondering how I could perform this two-leg file transfer or is there is a better approach than the one I am currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ssh ProxyJump. Create\edit config file in ~/.ssh

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

If there is no ~/.ssh folder in your home dir create it

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh; chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

And the config must be 600

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

In this file you can create ssh aliases to your servers like so

```
Host server1 # ssh-alias name
HostName 192.168.0.1 # server name or ip address
User user # user to login
```

Asssume that there is two(or more) servers but you can reach them only from server1

```
Host server2 # ssh-alias name
HostName 192.168.0.2 # server name or ip address
User user # user to login
ProxyJump server1 # jump server
```

And server3 only from server2

```
Host server3 # ssh-alias name
HostName 192.168.0.3 # server name or ip address
User user # user to login
ProxyJump server3 # jump server
```

This config will create "chain" of servers to access to remote hosts with simple name

```
ssh server3
```

Or copy files\dirs between them

```
scp some_file server3:/home/user/
```

But this method is best use with RSA key autentification

Answer (score 3):

`scp` can already handle the details of connecting to the destination via a jump server. No additional scripting is needed.

```
scp -o ProxyJump user@jumphost /path/to/local_file final_server:/destination/path
```

Comment: I didn't know about ProxyJump. I was writing out an answer using `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: I think `ProxyJump` is a newer option (at least, newer than `ProxyCommand`), to handle common uses of `ssh` as the proxy command.

Comment: I had to add quotes around ProxyJump user@jumphost. Like this `scp -o 'ProxyJump user@jumphost' /path/to/local_file final_server:/destination/path`